# Bibtex: adjust bst to include doi as link only?

Tags: bibtex, doi, urlbst

I would like to have the doi shown in the bibliography as a single link, i.e. it should be shown as an hyperlink with title `doi` instead of printed as `doi:10.1038/s1231`.

I found the nice [urlbst](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urlbst), which allowed to take any bib style and have the doi printed as text, using: `urlbst --doi  --hyperref style.bst styleNew.bst` This even nicely prints `doi:10.1038/s1231` while adding a hyperlink with `https://doi.org/10.1038`

To have doi shown as hyperlink, I tried `\renewcommand{\url}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{doi}}`, however I am facing two issues:

- This only works for bibtex `URL` fields, not `doi` fields
- This actually prints URLs, while I would like only to show dois.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to indulge in a bit of bst style-hacking, then you could take your `.bst` file, as generated by `urlbst`, and make the following replacement:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    %{ doiprefix doi * doiurl doi * make.href }
    { "doi" doiurl doi * make.href }
  if$
}
```

(that is, replacing the commented-out line with the line below it).

That appears to produce the formatting you're looking for, with just ‘doi’ as the link text.

Hmm: it occurs to me that `urlbst` could make this easier.  There are already a couple of settings advertised at the top of the generated `.bst` files.  It wouldn't be unreasonable to add a further switch to have the `.bst` files generate `\doi{<content-of-doi-field}` instead of what they do now.  Looking at my diary, it looks like I'll have some urgent procrastination coming up, so...

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks! Is there a way to only add the doi, and not the URL?

Comment: Do you mean displaying only the DOI, but not making it a hyperlink? You should be able to get that by making the fifth line, above, just `{ doi }`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean only considering the `doi` field of the bibtex, not the `url` one (they tend to be redundant).

Comment: @Matifou I've released [v0.9 of urlbst](https://ctan.org/pkg/urlbst), which includes a switch when running `urlbst` (namely `--setting doiform 1`) which will generate the DOI as `\doi{xxx}`, which means that you can define a `\doi` macro however you wish.  It's a bit of a general escape-hatch, but might give the flexibility you need.  Thanks for the (implicit) suggestion!

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot for your great work!

Comment: I used `--setting doiform=1` together with `\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi}}` for this. Note adding `http://dx.doi.org` can be redundant (as 50% of doi are formatted as `https://doi.org/10.1016`, but luckily a link like `http://dx.doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016` will still work.

Comment: The other question I had was about only showing `doi` and not `url`, seems like `econ.bst` has the option, see line 717: https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/econ-bst/blob/master/econ.bst . I guess this is not possible with urlbst? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou urlbst currently skips (or aims to skip) printing both DOI and URL where they're equal.  But perhaps this relates to your earlier comment about the redundant addition of dx.doi.org (.bst doesn't have much of a string-wrangling library)

Comment: @Matifou ...and now urlbst 0.9.1 does do some basic checking for `https://doi.org/` (and only that string).  The new version is uploaded and should be on its way to mirrors in 24 hours.  Thanks for the implicit suggestion!